# Call action of another control using jQuery $.ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have two controller, **C1** and **C2**.
**C2** has a method named **M2** which is returning a `JsonResult`.
Now i am calling method **M2** from view **V1** using `$.ajax` call but I guess that the relative path to **C2/M2** is not working fine.

```
$.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "/C2/M2",
         success: function (data) {
             alert(data);
         }
});
```

**Notice:**
View **V1** is rendered using controller **C1**
What is wrong with this call ?

```
public class C1 : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Package(object Id)
    {
        return View("PackageO");
    }
}

public class C2: Controller
{
    public JsonResult SelectAll()
    {
        return Json(_rep.SelectAll(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Under `ready()` of **jQuery** in View 'PackageO' i am using **IIFE**

```
$(function () {
      var resultant = "";
      $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "./C2/SelectAll",
           //url: "@Url.Action('SelectAll', 'C2')",
           done: function (data) {
                alert("success");
           },
           fail: function (ex) {
                alert("fail");
           }
      });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should **never** *hard-code URLs* in `MVC`.

Instead use `@Url.Action`.

```
url: '@Url.Action("FunctionName", "ControllerName")',
```

If this doesn't fix your problem tell us what kind of error(s) are you getting.

Also, for the sake of your sanity, use the fail method.

```
$.ajax("http://url")
    .done(function() {
    alert("success");
})
    .fail(function() {
    alert("error");
})
```

One last note, `success` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8; you should use `done` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.i am getting following error<br/>"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:20097/Package/Package/@Url.Action(%22SelectAll%22,%20%22Bank%22)"

Comment: Is that URL correct? If it is then the problem is in that controller. Unless you are forgetting to send some required parameters...

Comment: i am self invoking this function under ready() of jquery as i want to populate dropdownlist

Comment: Does your project run OK? Can you navigate manually to C2's SelectAll?

Comment: I suggested you to use Url.Action and you have failed at copy pasting my code and changing the strings.

Comment: i have done Url.Action in both ways but it does not work either way. secondly i called SelectAll method from C2 and it was working fine.

Comment: You need to use `Url.Action` as @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu has indicated. If your getting a `500 Internal Server Error` then you controller method is probably throwing an exception.